# Unable to fix malformed JSON in wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce for the first time with wordpress in order to setup an e-commerce site. Everything is installed properly from wordpress to woocommerce plugin and the theme. But the problem resides.

Kindly check below image[image]

I keep getting the same error again and again, I reinstalled the entire wordpress site but no luck. I followed few tutorials wherein they instruct to open browser console and check for a red line which I don't receive in my console.

What I get is in the image below
[image]

Also, somehow I am not even able to select another payment option other then cash on delivery which I have installed on my site. I have been struggling for last 3 days, but no luck! Kindly do not down vote this question. As I am feeling helpless at the moment.

The site is fashionburst.in

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue with a site

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who might run into this issue, try to turn on debugging in `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

And then read the log file in `wp-content/debug.log`. I had a PHP error in one of my plugin's hooks and since the checkout is processed with JS, the checkout.min.js threw this error. Log file should give you proper error report (in my case I was using undefined PHP function).